# Can I have two different Styles in a CustomControl

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Can we have two different styles in generic.xaml setter template Property

Something like:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:customLocalFolderButton">
                  **<----Style 1---->**
                  </ControlTemplate TargetType="local:customLocalFolderButton">
                 </Setter.Value>

              <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:customLocalFolderButton">
                  **<----Style 2---->**
                  </ControlTemplate TargetType="local:customLocalFolderButton">
                 </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Now I want to load the styles , as per the requirement. The 1st Style Can have a Red Folder and the Second Style Can have Blue Folder .

The user can choose any of the theme and the choosen style(Either RedFolder or Blue) should be applied in the customControl it self.

Thanks,
Subhen

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have two implicit default styles. This would need to be done through static resources instead.